# Allow user to only Print and Sign for an envelope

Tags: docusignapi

For users in countries where e-Signatures are not recognized, I would like to get only Wet Signed documents.

Is there any way in Docusign where I can configure an envelope to be signed only using Print and Sign - Upload or Fax?

I tried not including a Sign Here tab in the document. In that case, the user is shown the option to Finish, or Print and Sign, and if the user clicks on Finish, Docusign automatically assumes that the user has signed the document which is not the case however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the REST API, there is a boolean you can set which will force the signer to sign on paper called: requireSignOnPaper

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Signers%20Recipient.htm

Comment: I think this should work, although to use this option, the feature  AllowRequireWetSign needs to be turned on. The feature can only be turned on by Docusign Account Managers as mentioned [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00009542)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use the [fax out](https://support.docusign.com/articles/How-do-I-send-a-DocuSign-document-by-fax-Fax-Out-feature) feature for these recipients

> I tried not including a Sign Here tab in the document. In that case, the user is shown the option to Finish, or Print and Sign, and if the user clicks on Finish, Docusign automatically assumes that the user has signed the document which is not the case however.

DocuSign does not assume the user has "Signed" the document, without any assigned tags a recipient is not required to take any action (but are given the option to), it's called [Free Form Signing](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/cdse-user-guide/Content/advanced-sending/free-form-signing.htm). The system does not require a signature in order for a transaction to be completed on the recipient side.