# Docusign REST API flow for signing pdf

Tags: rest, web-applications, docusignapi, sign

I have an app that creates a pdf that the user has to sign online. I want to somehow upload the document and receive it back, signed by the customer, by "hand".

I tried to follow the quickstart guide, but it does not allow to sign documents (template fields are greyed out), and they are not created dynamically, so I can´t use that approach.

What is the best workflow for achieving this? I mean, what APIs would I need to call and in what order? Has anyone gone through this process before?

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on what you mean by "hand"?

If you mean they need to print the document, sign it and then upload it then there's a similar question here [Allow user to only Print and Sign for an envelope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525739/allow-user-to-only-print-and-sign-for-an-envelope). The feature itself is called [Print & Sign](https://support.docusign.com/guides/signer-guide-signing-sign-on-paper-new)

REST API Reference: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/create#EnvelopeRecipients

Have a look at `signer > requireSignOnPaper` definition on that page.

Comment: "By hand" means that the user has to draw his signature on the screen, with the mouse or with a finger if on a cell phone.